# How to pass JsonResult to PartialView in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass JsonResult to partialView, I am able to return JsonResult to normal view but do not know how it can be passed to partial view. JsonResult which is being passed to normal view is

```
public JsonResult Search(int id)
{
    var query = dbentity.user.Where(c => c.UserId == id);
    return Json(query,"Record Found");
}
```

but want to know how it cant be returned to partial view such as

```
public JsonResult Search(int id)
{
   var query = dbentity.user.Where(c => c.UserId == id);
   return PartialView(query,"Record Found");
}
```

Comment: By definition, your code `return PartialView(query,"Record Found")` contains 2 arguments, the first one should be view name, second one should be model type. There are two more overload methods contains either model or view name.

Comment: A controller action can only return one type of action result. What exactly is your goal?

Comment: I want to return JsonResult to partialView something like                return Json(PartialView,query)

Comment: you are using wrong return type change to abstract ActionList

Comment: why dont you return rendered partial view as jsonobject. Render you Partial View with your model and return the result and after obtaining result from jquery change the html of the control with new rendered string.

Answer (score 1):

Use action:

```
public ActionResult Search(int id)
{
   var query = dbentity.user.Where(c => c.UserId == id);
   return PartialView(query);
}
```

And on view convert Model into Json object

```
<script>
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

*I want to return JsonResult to partialView something like return Json(PartialView,query) – user3026519 Nov 24 '13 at 10:40*

I'm assuming you want to return Json result containing a rendered partial view? That being said you can use create helper method to convert the view into a string and then pass it to the Json result. Below is a possible solution:

Your helper method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper method to render views/partial views to strings.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The controller</param>
/// <param name="viewName">The name of the view belonging to the controller</param>
/// <param name="model">The model which is to be passed to the view, if needed.</param>
/// <returns>A view/partial view rendered as a string.</returns>
public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
```

Calling the action:

```
public ActionResult Search(int id)
{
    var query = dbentity.user.Where(c => c.UserId == id);
    return Json(RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "Search", query));
}
```